# Various debug modes of windbg

Tags: debugging, kernel, windbg

I would like also ask about one thing: somewhere I've read that windbg supports multiple modes of debugging and one of those modes is some kind of kernel debugging where system is normally running and does not wait for windbg breakpoints etc. Is this local kernel debugging mode? Also if anybody can clarify very briefly the differences between [Non invasive debugging](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff552274%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [Dormant mode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh406303%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). I did not catch it from MSDN. Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Debugging types

You can distinguish several times

a) between kernel debugging and user mode debugging (application debugging)

b) between live debugging (running system) and post mortem debugging (crash dump analysis)

c) between local debugging and remote debugging

so in total there are 8 combinations of debugging.

For local live kernel debugging you need to put the Windows kernel in debug mode. If you don't want that, you can get "pseudo"-live local kernel debugging with [SysInternals LiveKd](https://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/sysinternals/bb897415.aspx).

### Noninvasive debugging

Noninvasive debugging is a subset of user mode debugging and best described by the article you already linked to (which is a copy of WinDbg help), which says:

> With noninvasive debugging, you do not have as many debugging actions. However, you can minimize the debugger's interference with the target application. Noninvasive debugging is useful if the target application has stopped responding.
>
> In noninvasive debugging, the debugger does not actually attach to the target application. The debugger suspends all of the target's threads and has access to the target's memory, registers, and other such information. However, the debugger cannot control the target.

### Dormant mode

Dormant mode is when WinDbg is running but has not attached to any target. E.g. if you just start WinDbg without any command line options and you have not pressed <kbd>F6</kbd> yet to attach to a process.

Comment: Thank you Thomas. The mentioned kernel debugging where system is normally running and does not wait for windbg breakpoints etc. is local kernel debugging (e.g. with LiveKd)? This reminds me the sort of non invasive debugging that you've described.

Comment: Noninvasive is also useful when you already have another debugger attached (say Visual Studio) but you want to inspect memory with Windbg.

Comment: This is doubly wrong. Local live kernel debugging is supported starting with Windows XP. This is [documented in the WinDbg help](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff553382%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). `LiveKd` on the other hand **does not** allow you to perform live local kernel debugging. It takes a snapshot of the memory and run WinDbg in crash dump analysis mode. If you open WinDbg run by `LiveKd` you can see the `-z foo.dmp` argument passed to it. `-z` is the [flag for loading a dump file](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff561306%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: You need to turn on kernel debugging for that (`bcdedit /debug on` or adding `/debug` in the `boot.ini` file on XP) for this to work, as with any case of live kernel debugging through WinDbg. `LiveKd` is indeed sometimes a good option; I'm not saying otherwise. I've used it more than once. But it gives you a static dump file, and doesn't allow you to **write** data into memory etc. (which you most likely shouldn't try anyway, but with "real" local kernel debugging you **can**, dangerous as it may be). And yes, the edit makes the answer much more accurate.

Comment: No thanks necessary. Once I can agree with the answer, I vote it up. :)